# Simple Beginner Loop Wont Close

Tags: while-loop

Practicing some stuff and I've been way beyond this simple of a concept but this loop won't close and I can't understand why.

ans = "Y"

```
while ans == "Y" or "y": 
    num = int(input("What's your number? "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("That number is even!\n")
    else:
        print("That number is odd!\n")
    ans = str(input("Do you have another number, Y/y or N/n? "))
```

So I declare the variable first so I can enter the loop then ask for it again on the tail side to close it out...but no matter what I enter it continues.

I'm sure it's simple like I said i'm way past this kind of thing but it won't close and I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be if ans == “Y” or ans == ”y”? Simple ”y” will always evaluate to true I guess. That’s why the loop never quits.

Comment: that's why (haven't even changed it yet)...knew I was brain freezing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the 'or "y"':

You should check if ans is Y or y which is correctly expressed as 'ans == "Y" or ans == "y"'

You as well needs to specify a starting condition for ans.

```
ans = "y"
while ans == "Y" or ans == "y":
    num = int(input("What's your number? "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("That number is even!\n")
    else:
        print("That number is odd!\n")
ans = str(input("Do you have another number, Y/y or N/n? "))
```